# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on raspberry pi only

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi, nio, nosuchmethoderror

I'm running Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2. My program works fine when I run it in Eclipse, and it also works fine when I run the .jar using windows cmd. However, putting that same .jar onto a raspberry pi, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Ljava/util/List;
```

The bits of code in question are

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import dataTypes.Detection;

public final class FileOperations {
// ...
    public static Detection readDetection(Path p) {
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p);
// etc ...
```

I'm partially convinced that the problem lies with my having incorrectly compiled the jar, but since I'm a complete novice at this sort of thing I don't know how to check I'm doing it right. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: What version of `java` are you running on the raspberry pi? Run `java -version` to find out.

Comment: Java version 1.7.0_40
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)

On the PC it's Java 1.8. I guess that might be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use [`java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-), which was introduced in Java 8. You're not going to be able to use that in Java 7.

Options:

- Upgrade to Java 8 on the raspberry pi
- Don't use any classes/methods which are specified to Java 8. (Change your Eclipse project to target a Java 7 JRE to enforce this)

As it happens, the overload of `readAllLines` which takes a `Path` and a `Charset` is available on Java 7, *and* that's a better overload to use anyway, so that you're explicit about which encoding you want to use. So change your code to:

```
// Or whichever Charset you really want...
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Ahah, that must be it! Thank you for solving this! I think I'm going to go with option 2 - one more quick question: how do I change the project to target a Java 7 JRE? I'm looking around but can't seem to find the right property...

Comment: @user2823789: I *think* you'll need to install a Java 7 JRE on your desktop as well, then just configure the Java Build Path for your project.

Comment: Righto, I'll do that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Rasberry Pi probably has Java ME (Micro Edition), which does not contain many of the methods in Java SE (Standard Edition) which you probably have on your machine running Eclipse.

Comment: Okay, so how do I go about fixing this? Do I have to simply try using a different way of reading the file (and if so, do you have any advice on what might work)?

Comment: The Javadoc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/index.html), I'll try to find some file operations... It might be in the Rasberry Pi library (if there is one) as well.

Comment: I very much doubt that it's Java ME. The raspberry pi is more capable than that...

Comment: There is an article over [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html) that might help. I remember people running web servers on it so should be a problem running Java SE on RPi.

Comment: Just checked and I'm using java 1.7 SE on the pi but java 1.8 on the PC.