# Android Studio Start Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Today i updated my gradle and after that updated my android studio to the latest version since the older version won't support gradle.
But after updating my android studio doesn't start.

Here is the error below:

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:47)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$$Lambda$14.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:711)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:358)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:220)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:135)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:123)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:119)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:111)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$$Lambda$29.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:196)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Ljava/util/List;
    at com.intellij.ide.ThreadDumpsDatabase.reapThreadDumps(ThreadDumpsDatabase.java:52)
    at com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor.initComponent(SystemHealthMonitor.java:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:518)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: You have to upgrade to Java 8
Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957425/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-on-raspberry-pi-only

Comment: @Curio I upgraded my java to ver 8 and restart my laptop but problem still persists.

Comment: @Gowthaman I can't open android studio then how can i even rebuild the project?

Comment: Maybe you have to reinstall android studio